# Waves of particles reacting to audio

Tags: javascript

I was curious to see if anyone has tried this, I'm trying to make a [wave of particles](https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_particles_waves.html) react to music. End goal is to make a reactive site like the [adult swim singles](http://www.adultswim.com/music/singles-2018) program website. If anyone knows how to do this or can help point me in the right direction please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @X3Friends -- this question is probably not a great fit for SO.  I'd recommend you review [ask].  I would say this would fall either in the category of "too broad" or "not on topic".  I'm sure there are many other forums that would be more helpful to you for this particular endeavor.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

GSAP and react-transition-group should help you.